# In a Tomcat cluster, how to share beans in an application?

Tags: java, tomcat, javabeans, cluster-computing

This might sound like a dumb or a simple question, but I really have little to no experience with clustering of any kind and I'm just curious if and how a certain scenario is possible.

Let's say I've set up a cluster of N Tomcat instances, and I've deployed my application `App1` across all N instances.

What would I need to do to be able to have certain beans in the application - not all, but some - be "shared" across the cluster?

i.e., if I had a bean for `WebsiteSettings`, I'd like to have some lookup process where the application could ask for the bean and be given an instance of it, and any updates to the bean's properties/values are also available to any other machines in the cluster, i.e., `WebsiteSettings.getGreeting()` would return the same value on all N machines whenever it was updated.

Do I need to set these beans up as MBeans, and have `App1` look them up via JMX? Will Tomcat's clustering support then take care of replicating changes in the MBean to all node's in the cluster automatically?

Answer (score 5):

Please take a look at [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/) - it allows you to have the same object (in a way) reside on many instances, where all the updates of the other nodes are done seamlessle in the JVM level and not in your code.

You may want to take a look at this for further information - [What Is Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/orgsite/What+Is+Terracotta)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a shared distributed cache.  There are several available which would easily give you this functionality.

Comment: This is an interesting approach that I hadn't really thought of, thanks. I'd still be interested to know of some of the more "traditional" methods though

Comment: I think this is the standard or traditional approach to your problem.